# Cannot redeclare class error in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have written a separate action class which is called from a controller like this:

1) protected/controllers/SoccerController.php

```
class SoccerController extends Controller
{
    public function actions() {
        return array (
            'index' => 'application\actions\soccer\IndexAction',
            'teamlist' => 'application\actions\soccer\TeamListAction'
        );
    }
}
```

2) protected/actions/soccer/IndexAction.php

```
class IndexAction extends CAction
{
    public $viewFile = 'teamoverview';

    /**
     * executes the action.
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $team = new SoccerTeam();
    $this->controller->render($this->viewFile, array('team'=>$team));
    }

}
```

when I call url http://localhost/test/soccer/index I get a fatal error Cannot redeclare class IndexAction in C:\wamp\www\test\protected\actions\soccer\IndexAction.php on line 25

Can any body help me why this error occurs ?

Comment: why are you writing a separate action class ?

Comment: Instead of having all the actions in a controller I tried to break down to different classes.

Comment: you could just create a separate module if you want or multiple controllers, if you think a single controller has too many actions.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering why this solution is not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/basics.controller):

> To define a new action class, do the following:
>
> ```
> class UpdateAction extends CAction
> {
>     public function run()
>     {
>         // place the action logic here
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In order for the controller to be aware of this action, we override
>   the `actions()` method of our controller class:
>
> ```
> class PostController extends CController
> {
>     public function actions()
>     {
>         return array(
>             'edit'=>'application.controllers.post.UpdateAction',
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In the above, we use the path alias
>   `application.controllers.post.UpdateAction` to specify that the action
>   class file is `protected/controllers/post/UpdateAction.php`.

So, `'index' => 'application\actions\soccer\IndexAction',` this is the cause of the error, try changing this to: 
`'index' => 'application.controllers.soccer.IndexAction',` or whatever your path is.